# How do I get index of line

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing

I'm reading the file, so how do I get the turns, or index for each line?

```
for line in excelRead:
    keywrds=[]
    title=line.split("+")
    title=[lines.strip()for lines in title]
    print title[0]
```

So, when I read my first line in excel, line variable is equal to line value in excel, but how do I find which turn it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, line in enumerate(excelRead, start=1):
    keywrds=[]
    title=line.split("+")
    title=[lines.strip()for lines in title]
    print title[0]
    print index
```

The `start` parameter to the `enumerate` indicates that you want to start the index at 1, instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for index, line in enumerate(excelRead, start=1):
    # use index as you wish
    keywrds=[]
    title=line.split("+")
    title=[lines.strip()for lines in title]
    print title[0]
```

`start=1` because by default it starts at `0`, but Excel's first row is row `1`.

You can find out more about the built-in `enumerate` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate).